# Xerces jar is a DOM parser or SAX parser

Tags: xml-parsing

I would like to know about Xerces.jar implementation 
is Xerces.jar a DOM parser or SAX parser.
When I try reading a huge XML file I am getting the following error message. Please help
java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.readObject(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor569.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1098)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1948)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1948)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1756)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both.

It's a dessert topping AND a floor wax :)

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-sax.html
- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html

PS:
Please post the space in the stack where the exception actually occurred.  You seem to have left it out :)

PPS:
Also look here:

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/schema.html

> Due to the way in which the parser constructs content models for
>   elements with complex content, specifying large values for the
>   minOccurs or maxOccurs attributes may cause the parser to throw a
>   StackOverflowError. Large values for minOccurs should be avoided, and
>   unbounded should be used instead of a large value for maxOccurs.

Consider turning schema checking OFF, or changing minOccurs/maxOccurs:

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html